# Load library jars with javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I am trying to analyze the code of a java project.
I have the project to be analyzed in a jar that I add to javassist path using insertClassPath function. Everything works fine if I try to access a class form the project.
The problem is that I need to access also the classes from the libraries the project uses.

I tried to add the library to the class path just like i did with the project jar, but I get a NotFoundException so i guess I am not giving the right path.

The code looks like this:

```
String jarFileName = "C:/Users/diana/Desktop/Test/ckjm.jar";
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    try{
        pool.insertClassPath(jarFileName);
        pool.insertClassPath("C:/Users/diana/Desktop/Test/ckjm/lib/bcel-5.2.jar");
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("error loading jar!!");
    }
```

I used the harcoded string just for testing purpose. The jar is in the lib folder or the project that was archived to a jar.
I am not sure how can i add a jar that is contained in another jar.

Note: if i keep the library as a separate jar (and give the path like: "C:/Users/diana/Desktop/Test/bcel-5.2.jar") it woks fine

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your target JAR is inside another JAR, you can use a [LoaderClassPath](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/LoaderClassPath.html) created using a [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) which is defined using a [JarURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) URL path of the JAR.

So assume you have a target JAR, **inner.jar**, embedded inside another JAR, **C:/Users/diana/outer.jar**.

Let's assume it is in a subdirectory called **lib**.

The URL of the outer JAR would be **file:/C:/Users/diana/outer.jar**.

The URL of the inner JAR would be **jar:file:/C:/Users/diana/outer.jar!/lib/inner.jar**.

You code to load this classpath would be:

```
URL cpUrl = new URL("jar:file:/C:/Users/diana/outer.jar!/lib/inner.jar");
URLClassLoader cpUrlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{cpUrl});
pool.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(cpUrlLoader));
```

Comment: I have tried this but still I can not access the classes from the jar.
The insertClassPath function does not throw an exception, but when I try to access a class using pool.get(className) I get NotFoundException